# Embed SVG in SVG and keep namespaces separated

Tags: css, svg, namespaces

Is there some way to embed `<svg>` inside `<svg>` and separate their namespace for classes and ids?

The idea is to make the code below render as two texts - one red and one blue without changing `<style>` contents (all embedded `<svg>` contents are from another file and trying to avoid touching it in any way).

There is option to keep embedded svg in separate file and use `<image href="..."/>` but the goal here is to merge bunch of svgs into one.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <svg>
        <style>
            #text-font {
                fill: red;
            }
        </style>
        <text id="text-font" x="50" y="50">TEST</text>
    </svg>
  
    <svg>
        <style>
            #text-font {
                fill: blue;
            }
        </style>
        <text id="text-font" x="100" y="100">TEST</text>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: All id values must be unique within a single document. This has nothing to do with namespaces.

Comment: But you can keep the duplicate IDs (in separate SVG files!) when you load each external  SVG in **shadowDOM**. Take inspiration from my [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Comment: What kind of application/framework are you using for concatenating all the SVG files?

Comment: @chrwahl I'm concatenating them with `xml` python module

Comment: @FamousSnake In that case I think you should reframe your question. The issue is how you can use Python to ensure that IDs are unique. More specifically I think that XSLT is relevant (and the Python module lxml), so that you ca generate new IDs. The major issue will be how the CSS selectors are transformed, but I guess that depend on the amount of and differences between the CSS in the different files.

Comment: @chrwahl that's exactly what I was trying to avoid by looking for some method to separate ids and classes namespaces because transforming css sounds too complex.